# Replace a very long string of commas at the end of the line with another string

Tags: sed

I have a CSV file formatted as such:

```
foo,5321,VFVYX,0010,,,,,,,,,,,,,
bar,35,HJU,1010,,,,,,,,,,,,,
baz,19865,,11101,,,,,,,,,,,,,
quux,,BZXY,101,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Each line ends with a very long sequence of commas (shortened here).

I need to replace all commas at the end of each line with the string `EOL`, while keeping the carriage return, so to obtain:

```
foo,5321,VFVYX,0010EOL
bar,35,HJU,1010EOL
baz,19865,,11101EOL
quux,,BZXY,101EOL
```

How to do this? I have tried

```
sed 's/,*$/EOL/g' filein.csv > fileout.csv
```

but this does not do the intended result (it inserts a single EOL line between each line of the input).

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Could this file have Windows line endings? even then, I would not expect a single EOL line, but does `sed 's/\r//g' file | sed 's/,*$/EOL/'` do what you expect? If not, you have other non-printing characters in the file. What is the output of `od -c file`? Finally, the `g` in `'s/,*$/EOL/g'` is pointless: when you are anchoring the regex with `$` there can only ever be one match per line so the `g` isn't relevant.

Comment: Good catch.  Now that you mentioned it, I realized that in fact the file has Windows line endings.

Comment: Solved the issue by first converting the file from Windows to Unix format via the command `dos2unix -n filewin.csv fileunix.csv`.  Cannot add this as an answer as the question was closed.